# How to return a Datatable by a [WebMethod]

Tags: c#, web-services, datatable

I have a webservice that should return the top 5 emails in my inbox and display them in a data grid. I put my data into a `DataTable` first. But keep getting errors

Here is my code, Am I missing anything or declaring something wrong?

```
[WebMethod]
    public DataTable DisplayMailList(String inMailServer, String inPort, bool inSSlCheck, String inUsername, String inPassword)
    {   
        objClient.Connect(inMailServer, int.Parse(inPort), inSSlCheck);
        objClient.Authenticate(inUsername, inPassword);

        int count = objClient.GetMessageCount();

        DataTable dtMessages = new DataTable(); // Creating datatable.
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("MessageNumber");
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("From");
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("Subject");
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("DateSent");
        dtMessages.TableName = "dtMessages";

        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = count; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            OpenPop.Mime.Message msg = objClient.GetMessage(i);

            dtMessages.Rows.Add();
            dtMessages.Rows[dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1]["MessageNumber"] = i; //Populateing Datatable
            dtMessages.Rows[dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1]["Subject"] = msg.Headers.Subject;
            dtMessages.Rows[dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1]["DateSent"] = msg.Headers.DateSent;

            counter++;
            if (counter > 5)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return dtMessages;
    }
```

Think the problem is public **DataTable** I had it declared as an object but that did not work ether .... sigh, what should I declare it as?
this is the error....

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the
>   XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot serialize
>   the DataTable. DataTable name is not set.

Comment: A [WebMethod] must be made static, your error says there is no name assigned... try assign a name (e.g. DataTable.TableName = "MyTable") as well.

Comment: You'll be better off, in the long run, if you stop using datatables and use strongly-typed objects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assigning a value to `dtMessages.DataTable` name will stop the serialization error, as the error message suggests.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add("testing");
        dt.TableName = "Blah";  // <---
        return dt;
    }
```

But I agree with Bob Horn that you're better off defining a class for your return value than using a DataTable.

Comment: That's assuming that it's an ASP.NET AJAX WebMethod. If it's in a classic ASP.NET web service it can't be static...

Comment: Actually whether it is static or not, classic ASP or not, is irrelevant to this answer.  The point was just to say "Add `dt.TableName = 'Blah';`".  I think your comment is distracting.

Comment: My comment was a response to an earlier comment, which has since been deleted. The earlier comment took issue with the fact that I hadn't included the "static" keyword on the method signature.

Comment: Ha! That they would worry about if it was static or not is also irrelevant - I believe the issue would occur either way - correct me if I'm wrong.  Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 6):

Just give a table name when create a datatable object

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("tablename");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

In your Application

```
      public void app()
      {
        try
        {
            DataTable dtInput = new DataTable();
            DataRow drRow;
            dtInput.Columns.Add("ID");
            dtInput.Columns.Add("Name");
            drRow = dtInput.NewRow();
            drRow["ID"] = 1;
            drRow["Name"] = "Star";
            dtInput.Rows.Add(drRow);
            dtInput.TableName = "Input";//Table name is mandatory to avoid serialization exception 
            DataTable dtOutput = new DataTable();
            dtOutput.TableName = "Output";//Table name is mandatory to avoid serialization exception 
            service.TestService(dtInput ,ref dtOutput);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
      }
```

In your service

```
      DataTable dtOutput= new DataTable();
      [WebMethod]
      public void TestService(DataTable dtInput , ref DataTable dtOutput)
      {
        DataRow drRow;
        drRow= dtInput.NewRow();
        drRow["ID"] = 2;
        drRow["Name"] = "Success";
        dtInput.Rows.Add(drRow);
        dtOutput= dtInput;
       }
```